# Is long API Url length a good practice?

Tags: rest, api, laravel-5.7

I am working on an Api of Medicine Reminder System . Here I have four Tables.

1. user
2. medicine
3. user_medicine ( Linking table of user and medicine )
4. medicine_reminder_time

user and medicine have many-to-many relationship. Thus, there is user_medicine table as linking table.

A user's can have many medicines. and Each medicines can have one or more reminder.

Thus, to maintain this, I have created a column of increment id in user_medicine (linking table) and make one-to-many relationship with medicine_reminder_time table.

For Api users to do CRUD on medicine_reminder_time, I have made route url like this :

`api/users/1/medicine/3/reminder`

Is this a standard way to make api urls? Or it should do with different way. please suggest.

Comment: There is no standard approach but your example seems reasonable.

Comment: In a REST architecture the setup of the URI is not of relevance to a client as it should neither parse it nor deduce knowledge from it. Clients are hinted about the relation the target resource stands in context to the current content via a link-relation name and an optional text summarizing the content in a human-friendly sentence or head line, similar to links used in HTML pages. REST is just a generalization of the browsable Web, therefore the same concepts of linking and teaching clients (through form representations) can and should be used.